# rails advanced query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

help me construct query on rails, please.
I have 2 models - Order (name, comment) and Task (order_id, sheets_num) (for example), Order has many Tasks. 
How I can select Orders, where the sum of their Tasks sheets_num's more than zero?

Answer (score 3):

rails 2.3.4 =>

```
Order.joins(:tasks).group(:order_id).having("sum(sheets_num) > 0").all
```

Comment: Good answer. On postgresql, you will need to tweak it though.